# draw circle with SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to draw a circle using SVG. The center of the circle is in array.
arr[i][0].x is the x-center and arr[i][0].y is y-center and arr[i][0].r is radius.

I tried it like this

```
svg.appendChild(circle);
        circle.cx.appendItem(arr[i][0].x);
        circle.cy.appendItem(arr[i][0].y);
        circle.r.appendItem(arr[i][0].r);
```

but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe `appendChild(circle)` et the _end_, after defining its attributes?

Comment: @JeremyThille use `setAttribute`

Comment: @JeremyThille the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

use setAttribute to set circle values.

```
 var circle = document.getElementById("circle")
        circle.setAttribute("cx", 60);
        circle.setAttribute("cy", 70);
        circle.setAttribute("r", 5);
 var svg = document.getElementById("svg1")
 svg.appendChild(circle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to create a circle, you have to use [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) to create/draw svg-objects and you have to use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) as well.

```
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
// it does not matter whether appendChild is put before or after setAttribute
svg.appendChild(circle);

circle.setAttribute("cx",100);
circle.setAttribute("cy",100);
circle.setAttribute("r",80);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is also working example.

```js
var svgn = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
var circle = document.createElementNS(svgn, "circle");
circle.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", 25);
circle.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", 25);
circle.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  20);
svg.appendChild(circle);
```

```html
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SVG DOM is a bit verbose but you can set the values directly if you want using element.property.baseVal.value as I've done below. You can plug in your array values instead of the hardcoded numbers I've used.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circle.cx.baseVal.value = 25;
circle.cy.baseVal.value = 25;
circle.r.baseVal.value = 20;
svg.appendChild(circle);
```

```html
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```